# How to convert entity object to XML

Tags: rest, resteasy

I have a legacy system with lots of entity (javax.persistence.Entity) object. Each of these entities has one-to-many relationship with other entities.

My requirement is to expose these entities by REST API. I am planning to use resteasy (the current product is run on jboss-7). My question is, what is the best way to design this?

Initially, I have thought of using JAXB annotated DTO object and convert all the entities using getter/setter. Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

```
Create One class like this

    public class Employee
    {
         public int employee_code {set; get; } 
         public string first_name {set; get; } 
         public string middle_name {set; get; }
         public string last_name {set; get; }
         public string designation {set; get; }
         public string department {set; get; }
         public string present_address {set; get; }
         public string permament_address {set; get; }
         public DateTime DOB {set; get; }
         public Double Gross_Salary {set; get; }
    } 

now create a method for xml creation using this namespace
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

public string CreateXML(Object YourClassObject){    
      XmlDocument xmlDoc =new XmlDocument();   //Represents an XML document, 
                // Initializes a new instance of the XmlDocument class.          
      XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new             XmlSerializer(YourClassObject.GetType());            
    // Creates a stream whose backing store is memory. 
       using (MemoryStream xmlStream =new MemoryStream())
       { 
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlStream, YourClassObject);
        xmlStream.Position = 0;
        //Loads the XML document from the specified string.
        xmlDoc.Load(xmlStream); 
        return xmlDoc.InnerXml;
       }
}

now call this method
string strView =CreateXML(YourClassObject);
```

Comment: this is too much work !! there is an alternative @http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74201/javaee-7-with-jpa-hibernate-and-jax-rs-resteasy but in that case I have to touch all my entities